# How to set the time in the slave pc to that of the master?

Tags: c#, datetime, synchronization, master-slave

I have to synchronize 2 pc's, so that both initiate certain actions almost simultaneously. The Master (1.st PC) tells the Slave (2.nd PC) when to initiate the procedure. Since there might be a delay, I measure it after connecting both PS's. The Master saves the time with `DateTime.Now` and sends a request to the Slave, which responds by sending his `DateTime.Now` value. The Master compares it afterwards. For now the Slave is on a virtual machine (oracle VM virtualBox). Although both PC's are in the same domain and receive their time from the same server, the slave time value is often smaller than that of the master, although it takes the `DateTime.Now` value later in the communication.

Is it possible to command the clock of the slave by the master? to set the value by hand, so to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all with the command line of

`net time \\computer /set`

You can call that as a process from c#

Comment: Great!, and you got me triggered to get in touch with the process class.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make it work. Without the `/set` the command gives me at least the time output in the cmd-shell. But in my code I don't get this output, even if I redirect it with `RedirectStandartOutput`.

Comment: If you cant set the time with that command, you dont have the rights on the pc

Comment: that is unfortunately true, but anyway thank you for the elegant solution and pointing me towards processes.